# Nullpointer exception on method with Nullable parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a static util method that I am calling with some values being null.

Here is the method signature that I am calling:

```
public static void logAndDisplayError(@Nullable Shell parentShell, String dialogTitle, String exceptionMessage, @Nullable Exception e, @Nullable Integer statusCode, boolean is1CD)
```

Here is the call to the method:

```
EclipseError.logAndDisplayError(getShell(), "Error Occured On Finish", message, null, null, true);
```

Inside the method, I am making a MessageDialog which is causing a null pointer.

Here is the MessageDialog creation:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(parentShell, 
                dialogTitle, 
                MessageDialog.getImage(Dialog.DLG_IMG_MESSAGE_ERROR), 
                getErrorMessage(e.getMessage(), e, statusCode), 
                MessageDialog.ERROR, 
                new String[]{"1CD Help", "Ok"}, 
                1);
```

The null pointer is occuring on this call in the MessageDialog:

```
getErrorMessage(e.getMessage(), e, statusCode)
```

So we know that e and statusCode are null. But I have Nullable defined in the getErrorMessage method...

```
private static String getErrorMessage(String exceptionMessage, @Nullable Exception e, @Nullable Integer statusCode)
```

Why is it throwing the null pointer?

Also, here is the @Nullable I am using:

org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable

Comment: `e.getMessage()` will NPE if `e` is `null`.

Comment: @khelwood oh duhhh I meant to pass exceptionMessage from the method parameter

Answer (score 0):

As you see, it's an eclipse annotation and it's just like a little comment for developers. Method will always let you give a null parameter into it.

Since you give your method a null parameter it's natural to throw a **NullPointerException**

I suggest you to use make a bean and use hibernate validator for this purpose.

[Hibernate validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) is an implementation of bean validation.

Rg

Comment: If it helped please mark as an answer for the rest of ppl.

Comment: This did not fix my issue.